# does ext3 need regular filesystem checks?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, ext3

i know there is some interval set per default for most distributions which is probably 60.

after 60 boots the filesystem will be checked.

but depending on how long the server was running between reboots - this could mean filesystem is not checked for months or even years.

on a medium to heavy used file system, is it wise to reboot every sunday at 1 o'clock for a automatic filesystem check?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to setup an `fsck` routine (which can cause high I/O) on the filesystems with heavy load. Rebooting a server frequently is never a good idea, it can lead to uncomfortable visits to the datacenter and unexpected downtime.